# for-loop returns only last result - php

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

My For loop looks like this

```
for ( $i = $startTime; $i <= $endTime; $i = $i + 86400 ) 
{
    $thisDate = date( 'Y-m-d', $i );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE date = '$thisDate'";
    $res = parent::_executeQuery($sql);
    $rs = parent::getAll($res);         

}

return($rs);
```

Now `return($rs)` will give me only last record. How do i get all results obtained inside for loop?

Comment: Store result in array _$rs[] = parent::getAll($res);_

Comment: What database driver are you using here? You really should be using prepared statements if that's an option, or at the very least, the proper escaping method. Simply dumping a value into your query is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try like this ,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE date BETWEEN  '".date('Y-m-d',$startTime)."' AND  '".date('Y-m-d',$endTime)."'";
$res = parent::_executeQuery($sql);
$rs = parent::getAll($res);
return($rs);
```

This will not require loop, and you will get all result in single query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$rs=array();
for ( $i = $startTime; $i <= $endTime; $i = $i + 86400 ) 
{
    $thisDate = date( 'Y-m-d', $i );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE date = '$thisDate'";
    $res = parent::_executeQuery($sql);
    array_push($rs,parent::getAll($res));      

}

return($rs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You use array 
like this

```
$rs=array();
for ( $i = $startTime; $i <= $endTime; $i = $i + 86400 ) 
{
$thisDate = date( 'Y-m-d', $i );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE date = '$thisDate'";
$res = parent::_executeQuery($sql);
$rs[]  = parent::getAll($res);         

}

return($rs);
```